# Import csv file and update existing table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, heroku-postgres, csv-import

I have a Postgres database on Heroku. I connect to it using pgadmin. I exported a table data to csv. Edited some of the cells and now I want to replace the same table with the corrected csv. But when I try to import the csv I get this error

[image: Error while importing updated csv on pgadmin]

I researched on this error. I understood that it tries to add more rows to existing table and the primary key clashes. But I couldn't get my solution. I want to replace the table with new updated csv.

Thanks

Comment: Import the CSV into a separate table then use SQL to update/insert the rows into the real table

Comment: or remove all rows and then copy

Comment: @VaoTsun Will it affect DB/Table schema if i do as you suggest?

Comment: yes, it will. you wrote you want to REPLACE data in table using data from csv. so you can IN TRANSACTION truncate table and copy from file, see if you like it and either COMMIT or ROLLBACK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL>begin;
BEGIN
Time: 0.366 ms
SQL>truncate table t;
TRUNCATE TABLE
Time: 3.068 ms
SQL>select * from t;
 t
---
(0 rows)

Time: 2.844 ms
SQL>copy t from '/tmp/t';
COPY 2
Time: 1.693 ms
SQL>select * from t;
               t
-------------------------------
 2014-10-09 08:09:58.241592+00
 2015-06-17 09:18:05.731139+00
(2 rows)

Time: 1.823 ms
SQL>end;
COMMIT
Time: 78.102 ms
```